# PHP : Output iCalendar File as Plain Text

Tags: php, calendar, icalendar

Can anybody recommend a script/some code to take an iCalendar Calendar File and output in plain text the events on that day?

**Current Code**

```
<?php
/**
 * This example demonstrates how the Ics-Parser should be used.
 *
 * PHP Version 5
 *
 * @category Example
 * @package  Ics-parser
 * @author   Martin Thoma <info@martin-thoma.de>
 * @license  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php  MIT License
 * @version  SVN: <svn_id>
 * @link     http://code.google.com/p/ics-parser/
 * @example  $ical = new ical('MyCal.ics');
 *           print_r( $ical->get_event_array() );
 */
require 'class.iCalReader.php';

$ical   = new ICal('THE URL');
$events = $ical->events();

$date = $events[0]['DTSTART'];
foreach ($events as $event) {
    echo "".$event['SUMMARY']."<br/>";
}
?>

<style>
body
{
    font-family: Segan;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [ICS-Parser](http://code.google.com/p/ics-parser/).

It does a very good job of converting the ICS into an array you can loop through and print how you like, an example is on their website.

Comment: How do I download it, because on downloads (http://code.google.com/p/ics-parser/downloads/list) it just says 'This project currently has no downloads.'?

Comment: Click on a file here: http://code.google.com/p/ics-parser/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk - and then choose 'View raw file'

Comment: Thanks. I've got it working, and it looks really good, but how could I change it to only display the things happening on the day it is accessed (today)? (I put what I've already got onto the question since it's too big to put here.)

Comment: get todays date from the array, you can probably use strtotime() and compare to todays date

Comment: I've got the current Unix Time via `$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
                   // 7 days; 24 hours; 60 mins; 60secs
$datestamp = date('Ymd');` and `$date = $events[0]['DTSTART'];
foreach ($events as $event) {
if ($event['DTSTART'] = $datestamp)
{
     echo "".$event['SUMMARY']."<br/>";
}
else
{
}` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: or `$date = $events[0]['DTSTART'];
foreach ($events as $event) {
if(strstr($event['DTSTART'], '$datestamp'))
{
     echo "".$event['SUMMARY']."<br/>";
}
else
{
}
}`

Comment: by the way some of the stuff isn't just the datestamp, but also has the time so like `20120311T100000`, I don't know if that makes any difference if I'm searching for if it contains anything

Comment: ah I know what I've done, I just needed to take out the 's around $datestamp and it works fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to READ or WRITE?
for reading I used in the past:

http://sevengoslings.net/icalendar

and

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/16660.html

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpicalendar/  --< i believe this one can also read but it is huge - you might just take a function or two from there

but - I understood by your question that you need to read - iCalender IS plain text.
You only need to open the file and plotline by line.

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("myfile.ics"); //read the file
$convert = explode("\n", $data); //create array separate by new line

for ($i=0;$i<count($convert);$i++)  
{
  echo $convert[$i].', '; //write value by index
}
?>
```

and then use regex or something else to give human-readeble format to the tags...

**EDIT I:**

I just found a function I used before :
It uses this class: http://www.kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/index.php
It was not written by me, but it worked for me in the past .
I do not remember the source for this function - If I will find it I will post it...

```
<?php

require_once 'iCalcreator/iCalcreator.class.php';

$filename = 'D:\Document\Docs\2007\05\iCal-20070508-082112.ics';

$v = new vcalendar(); // initiate new CALENDAR
$v->parse($filename);

# get first vevent
$comp = $v->getComponent("VEVENT");

#print_r($comp);
$summary_array = $comp->getProperty("summary", 1, TRUE);
echo "summary: ", $summary_array["value"], "\n";

$dtstart_array = $comp->getProperty("dtstart", 1, TRUE);
$dtstart = $dtstart_array["value"];
$startDate = "{$dtstart["year"]}-{$dtstart["month"]}-{$dtstart["day"]}";
$startTime = "{$dtstart["hour"]}:{$dtstart["min"]}:{$dtstart["sec"]}";

$dtend_array = $comp->getProperty("dtend", 1, TRUE);
$dtend = $dtend_array["value"];
$endDate = "{$dtend["year"]}-{$dtend["month"]}-{$dtend["day"]}";
$endTime = "{$dtend["hour"]}:{$dtend["min"]}:{$dtend["sec"]}";

echo "start: ", $startDate, "T", $startTime, "\n";
echo "end: ", $endDate, "T", $endTime, "\n";

?>
```